# Maven commands failing

Tags: maven

I am trying to build a project using maven. I have a properties tag which has the following links in pom.xml-

```
<properties>
   <release_deploy_repo>http://.../releases</release_deploy_repo>
   <plugin_repo>http://.../public</plugin_repo>
   <central_repo>http://.../public</central_repo>
</properties>
```

and then under repositories, i have

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repo</name>
        <url>${central_repo}</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

when i try mvn clean install, i get this error -

${central_repo} not found. Any idea what i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your properties section?

Comment: Sorry, i added it now. It was not formatted correctly.

Comment: can you post the complete pom.xml you are using? are parts of the configuration in a profile thats not active?